# A float set to 0.1 compares false against 0.1

Tags: c

```
 int main()   
    {
            float f = 0.1;
            if (f == 0.1)
                printf("True");
            else
                printf("False");
        }
```

I am just a beginner in c. I don't understand the behavior of the above program. The output is false. Why??

Comment: I just googled the first line in your code.....

Comment: Do not ignore compiler's warnings. There's always a reson for them...

Comment: @Adriano Nice quote in your profile. But writing a ununderstandable code is a good technique to insure you'll never be fired ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun LOL I'm still working on that problem...

Comment: Probably bad form to post the code as the title to a question.

Comment: @Adriano What compiler warning would you expect here? This program could have been written by someone who knew what they was doing. How is the compiler supposed to know the difference?

Comment: When this question comes up, I traditionally mention this blog post that I wrote: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Comment: @PascalCuoq if VC he'lll get C4244 by default (...possible loss of data). If GCC well I **Always** keep -Wconversion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0.1` is a `double` literal.

As `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in floating point, a `float` set to 0.1 will compare false against a `double` set to 0.1.

Your comparison would behave as intended if you use a `float` literal: `0.1f` (note the suffixed `f`: not to be confused with your variable name):

```
float foo /*renamed for clarity*/= 0.1;
if (foo == 0.1f){
     /*this will compare true*/
```

Comment: might want to add that, if `float` is the desired type, then `float foo = 0.1f;`  and `if (foo == 0.1f) puts("True");` would probably be what most people write

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: good point: I've edited. Perhaps a full answer would mention promotion of the floating point type to a double type, but I think that's outside the question scope.