# comparing float values with double resulting different behaviour

Tags: c

I found many questions.But none helps me

```
      float x = 0.1;
      x == 0.1
```

The above code returns false. since i try to compare double precision value with single precision x.

```
      float x = 0.5
      x == 0.5
```

This one returns true. I cant find why is it returning true?? Any suggestions ??

EDIT : So how do i identify which value has same representation in both precisions??

Comment: `x == 0.1f` is more likely to compare true (but still not guaranteed)

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855633/a-float-set-to-0-1-compares-false-against-0-1?rq=1

Comment: Try `printf("%.20e\n", x);printf("%.20e\n", 0.1);` to see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x == 0.1
```

`0.1`  is not of type `float` but of type `double`. `float` and `double` don't have the same precision. `0.1f` is of type `float`.

Why it works with `0.5` is because `0.5` has an exact representation in both `float` and `double` (in binary IEEE-754) types.

Comment: +1 please see my edits. and let me know why it is downvoted??

Comment: because there are so many duplicates here

Answer (score 0):

It is because of float/double representation in memory, you are seeing this behavior.

Please see [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal)

Comment: Please explain more, this is not an answer.